# python:get dict object from a string

Tags: python, string, dictionary, get

I have create dict dynamiquly from a list with :

```
exec("mydict_%=%" % (key, value))
```

i try to get a objet from a string like:

```
def getdict(String):
   code ...
   return dict


mydict = []
mydict = getdict("mydict_sample")
```

have you the solution ?

Comment: You should use a list instead of defining multiple variables.

Answer (score 0):

`ast.literal_eval` can evaluate strings that represent python dicts. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: thanks a lot : Safely evaluate an expression node or a string